# Ruby: What is considered global, and how do you avoid it?

Tags: ruby, singleton, global-variables, closures

I am having a tough time grasping the idea of completely avoiding globals in Ruby.

To my understanding, if I define a method, the method would be considered global because I can call the method later on in the script. Same goes for classes. Can you completely avoid globalsl?

Research has pointed my inconclusively towards closures and singleton methods but I am still having trouble understanding how I would 'completely avoid globals.'

EDIT: I have also programmed a bit in JavaScript and used closure as follows to avoid the use of any globals: `(function(){...})();` Can something similar be done in Ruby?

Comment: "To my understanding, if I define a method, the method would be considered global because I can call the method later on in the script." Every method that is defined is a method of some object. When you write code or define a method at the top level, it is in the context of the `main` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to understand the reasoning behind avoiding globals. The main reason is avoiding global state. By storing variable information in a global variable, you are allowing components of the program to behave differently when used in the same way at different times. This usually results in unintended side-effects, causing testing and maintenance issues. Global classes or methods are unable to change (not considering reflection) and are not an issue because of that.

Another thing you may have associated with globals is namespace pollution, which can be partially resolved by nesting namespaces in a way that groups components semantically. Those are still global, though and thus not really avoidable.

Comment: Apologies for edit, meant to edit my post but I am new to this :(

Comment: @user3019655: No worries ;)

Answer (score 0):

Modules and Classes as globals are not a problem.

You could use a module to conceal a class, but ultimately you're going to have *some* globals.

Avoiding global variables and methods would be advised, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have also programmed a bit in JavaScript and used closure as follows to avoid the use of any globals: `(function(){...})();` Can something similar be done in Ruby?

Comment: You might be avoiding it purposely. JavaScript has some of its own globals like `Object`, `Function`, `Array`, and others.

Comment: Is there a way to purposely avoid it in Ruby? Even if its not practical I am curious :)

Comment: If you insist upon comparing to JavaScript, you're going to continue to struggle. They're very different languages with very different idioms.